# Handling SQL CRUD queries in java

Tags: java, sql, odbc

I'm trying to handle CRUD queries in java. so far i have two methods;

```
public void query(String query) {
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        conn.commit();
        conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("cannot perform this query");
    }
}
protected void mod(String query) {
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("cannot perform this query");
    }
}
```

Yes, half the code is missing, but its not important. the class has 3 fields, Connection conn, Statement stmt and ResultSet rs. conn and stmt are set in the constructor method.

I have split the method in two because an exception was thrown when inserting, deleting or updating a table as part of the JDBC spec.

The code works well, but i would like to be able to detect and use the correct method for the type of query i am passing into the class. Is this possible? if so how?

Comment: Bad code.  I don't see where you're cleaning up any resources.  This doesn't add much value.  I'd look at something like Spring jdbcTemplate before writing my own.

Comment: Fair concern. The goal here is to have a console type application, The user shouldn't need to learn java to operate it. Seems more simple if i reduce complexity.

Comment: I don't think you've reduced much complexity here.  You've eliminated a little boilerplate with those try/catch blocks, but even those are not done well.  Wring that message is less info than you'd get from the full stack trace.  "cannot perform this query" - which one?  No idea.  Printing to System.out is a bad choice; logging would be better.  Your SQL resources must be class members.  No pooling that i can see.  Statement and ResultSet should be method local and closed in finally block.

Comment: People write CRUD applications all the time that don't require users to learn Java or SQL.  You need to do more than this.

Comment: If you want to inspect the other -20k lines of code you are more than welcome to, but I don't think the rest of StackExchange does.

Comment: Not really.  It would not be a pleasant experience judging from the little bit I saw.  This a buy versus build decision.  There are lots of persistence frameworks out there for Java.  I'd recommend using one rather than writing a bad one on your own.  Spring is terrific.  Time to learn something new.

Comment: I've looked and Spring doesn't fit the criteria.

Comment: I doubt that very much.  You didn't understand Spring.  You don't need all of it; just the JDBC template.